# External WM_DESTROY received for QWidgetWindow in embedded QWindow

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to add a QWidget to a QQuick 2 application.
The approach is the following:
Create a QQuickItem derived object, which creates the QWidget in an initialize function. The QWindow is obtained from the QWidget and reparented to the "main" QQuickWindow.
During runtime the result is very good (it looks like a normal view, not an external window).

However when I close the main window I receive:
*External WM_DESTROY received for  QWidgetWindow(0x202b3a4ffe0, name="QWidgetClassWindow") , parent:  QWindow(0x0) , transient parent:  QWindow(0x0)*

Any idea how to avoid this warning?

QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QWidgetWrapper 1.0
import QtQml 2.12

Item {
    id: root

    QWidgetWrapper {
        id: ewas
        anchors.fill: parent

        Component.onCompleted: {
            initialize(Window.window)
        }
    }
}
```

Cpp:

```
#pragma once
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <QWindow>

class QWidgetWrapper : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    
public:
    QWidgetWrapper(QQuickItem *parent = nullptr) : QQuickItem(parent) {}
    
    ~QWidgetWrapper() {

    }

    Q_INVOKABLE void initialize(QWindow *window) {
        m_widget = new QWidget();
        m_widget->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
        m_widgetWindow = QWindow::fromWinId(m_widget->winId());
        m_widgetWindow->setParent(window);
        m_widget->show();
    }


private:
    QWidget *m_widget = nullptr;
    QWindow *m_widgetWindow = nullptr;
};
```

Comment: it seems to me that there is a mistake in the general approach. You shouldn't mix Qt Widgets and Qt Quick, these are two completely different technologies. this is besides the fact that you can always do the same in pure QML.

Comment: If I could I would prefer QML. But I am dealing with third party QWidgets. So there is not much chance to get QML from there